# How to make a nested for loop more efficient and use with apply

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

I am trying to transform a functioning nested for loop into use with apply. I hope this will make it a lot faster. (from what I read it should, although this is not always true)  There are some 150K rows in the main dataframe to loop through...incredibly time consuming

I have written a for loop in R to check if date.time in df1 lies between two date.times in df2 and if the the codes in df1 and df2 match, location in df2 is then pasted into df1

Below is subset sample data

```
df1<-structure(list(date.time = structure(c(1455922438, 1455922445, 
1455922449, 1455922457, 1455922459, 1455922461), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), code = c(32221, 32222, 32221, 32222, 
32222, 32221)), .Names = c("date.time", "code"), row.names = 50000:50005, class = "data.frame")

df2<-structure(list(Location = 11:12, Code = 32221:32222, t_in = structure(c(1455699600, 
1455699600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), t_out = structure(c(1456401600, 
1456401600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = c("Location", 
"Code", "t_in", "t_out"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 11:12)
```

For loop which works correctly, but takes to long:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)[1]){
  for (j in 1:nrow(df2)){
    ifelse(df1$code[i] == df2$Code[j]
           & df1$date.time [i] < df2$t_out [j]
           & df1$date.time [i] > df2$t_in [j],
           df1$Location [i] <- df2$Location [j],
           NA)
  }
}
```

I have made it part way with this:

```
ids <- as.numeric(df2$Location)
f <- function(x){
  a <- ids[ (df2$t_in < x) & (x < df2$t_out)  ]
  if (length(a) == 0 ) NA else a
}   

df1$Location <- lapply(df1$date.time, f)
```

This returns two numbers as the date.time in df1 lies between t_in and t_out hence why there is a requirement for codes in each dataframe to match when the location is pasted

Any pointers greatly appreciated

Comment: It would be ideal if you could provide a slightly better test case where some of the i,j combinations were not satisfied by hte time conditions. In any case, please report back on the system.time results.

Comment: You may try with the sqldf package see if transforming your df to local database then perform queries on it helps your speed.

Answer (score 3):

The package `data.table` has overlapping range joins that can do this very quickly. The function you are looking for is `foverlaps`. Here's an example with a little bit of cleaning before using `foverlaps`:

```
require(data.table)

dt1 <- data.table(df1)
dt2 <- data.table(df2)

## need to create a range in dt 1 to find overlaps on
dt1[,start:=date.time]
dt1[,end:=date.time]

## clean up names to match each other
setnames(dt2,c("Location","Code","start","end"))
setnames(dt1,c("code"),c("Code"))

setkey(dt1,Code,start,end)
setkey(dt2,Code,start,end)

## use foverlaps with the additional matching variable Code
out <- foverlaps(dt1,dt2,type="any",
                 by.x=c("Code","start","end"),
                 by.y=c("Code","start","end"))

## more renaming and selection of the same subset of columns
setnames(out,"i.start","date.time")
out <- out[,.(date.time,Code,Location)]
```

Which gives the output:

```
> out
             date.time  Code Location
1: 2016-02-19 14:53:58 32221       11
2: 2016-02-19 14:54:09 32221       11
3: 2016-02-19 14:54:21 32221       11
4: 2016-02-19 14:54:05 32222       12
5: 2016-02-19 14:54:17 32222       12
6: 2016-02-19 14:54:19 32222       12
```

Comment: Probably faster than my triple `outer` approach, but I hope the OP will report on the `system.time`-results for both approaches versus his double for-loop approach.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to build a "loop-less" version that does not depend on either `for` or `apply`. See if it's any faster:

```
trans <- which( outer(X=df1$code, Y=df2$Code,'==') & 
                outer(df1$date.time , df2$t_in, ">") & 
                outer(df1$date.time, df2$t_out , "<")  , arr.ind=TRUE)
df1$Location [ trans[,1] ] <- df2$Location [ trans[,2] ]
df1
#------
                date.time  code Location
50000 2016-02-19 14:53:58 32221       11
50001 2016-02-19 14:54:05 32222       12
50002 2016-02-19 14:54:09 32221       11
50003 2016-02-19 14:54:17 32222       12
50004 2016-02-19 14:54:19 32222       12
50005 2016-02-19 14:54:21 32221       11
```

The three calls to outer will build `i` by `j` matrices that are `TRUE` when three separate conditions are satisfied, they are `AND`-ed to give a joint satisfaction result, and then the `which( . , arr.ind=TRUE)` returns a matrix where the `i` values are in the first column and the `j` values are in the second column, so one can use ordinary `[<-` assignment of the corresponding vectors.